# How to Get elevation in route calculation by Fleet Telematics service (HERE Map)

Tags: here-api

I´m using HERE Map Api and I am currently obtaining the route elevation through the **Routing service**, but it does not include information on toll cost, which does include the **Fleet Telematics** service and I need both the elevation and the toll cost.

**Is it possible to obtain the lift and toll cost from the same service? In a single call?** It is not indicated in the Fleet Telematics documentation how to obtain the elevation.

Comment: would it be possible to elucidate more about the use of lift or elevation for your use case which you are fetching from route API ? is Elevation being used in other calculations too ?

Comment: We use the elevation value to generate a graph of elevation and obtain the maximum and minimum elevation of the route. Elevation information is included in each shape in the route calculation service, but the same shape does not include elevation information in the Fleet Telematics service, using returnelevation param too

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the standard HERE Routing API does not provide toll costs and the Fleet Telematics Routing API which provides toll cost information does not return elevation information. You will have to continue using them as you are now. We can suggest an extra `returnElevation` parameter for the Fleet Telematics `calculateroute` API as a new feature.